# What's the equivalent of drupal_build_css_cache()?

Tags: 8, css-js-aggregation

Our client uses an external website for some of their pages. This provider does not enable us to theme their website directly, but they do allow us to load a single JS file from the Drupal site that we maintain.

We create this JS file through a Drupal route/controller, assembling the header and footer blocks, including CSS and JS files, and inserting them into the content by appending them to the appropriate elements.

We've ported all of the functionality to Drupal 8 from 7 and it's more efficient than before. However, we used to use drupal_build_css_cache() to aggregate the subset of CSS files from themes and modules that we need before injecting them into the website's head.

Keeping in mind that all we're delivering to the external website is a single JS file (so we can't attach a library in the usual way), is there a way of programatically creating an aggregated CSS file in Drupal 8, as that function used to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`drupal_build_css_cache()` is a Drupal 7 function that was removed very early in the Drupal 8 development cycle. The change notices back then weren't very good, so simply searching for that function name won't find anything. (Change notices may be found at https://www.drupal.org/list-changes). The relevant change notice is [Pluggable CSS & JS preprocessing (aggregation/minification)](https://www.drupal.org/node/2034675)

This does not say what `drupal_build_css_cache()` was replaced with, but searching the code of the patch that removed the function shows that the code of that function is now in the `asset.css.collection_optimizer` service (implemented in `\Drupal\Core\Asset\CssCollectionOptimizer`)

Answer (score -2):

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21common.inc/function/_drupal_flush_css_js/8.5.x

Try the above. it will clear all caches of JS and CSS.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_flush_all_caches/8.5.x

It will clear all caches and rebuild.

Comment: The question does not ask about clearing caches, it asks about aggregating CSS. Your answer does not address the question.

Comment: As anonymous states above, that's not even remotely close to what I was asking.

Comment: Your answer explains how to use core functions to clear the cache. This is not what OP asked for. Thanks for taking time to post an answer anyway.